# Command-line "top" command executed programmatically via Android runtime returns same CPU usage data every time

Tags: android, shell, adb

Command-line "top" command executed programmatically via Android runtime returns same CPU usage data every time:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n3 -d1")

Even adding that "-n3" switch still returns the same %cpu, %user, %sys and %idle for each iteration.
How can I invoke the top command to track the actual proper CPU usage data?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try?

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n100 -d1");
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String result;
            while ((result = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("output", result);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I still cannot get read the real runtime value of those 4 fields no matter what variant of the "top" command I use. I see constant values in those fields every time, even though I can see the process info changing in real time. I'm runnin on OS 8.x. It seems that there's no easy way of reading overall system CPU info; I'm only able to read my own process' CPU % information - and nobody else's